# Create signature on image Android?

Tags: android

I'm making an application to create signature on file image. Here, I will load the image file from the memory card to the application and use Canvas Paint can create a signature by hand through the draw.

The problem here is the application requirements for customers to sign in a specific location. My code allows customers can sign in anywhere the customer wants, like paint on the windows. Now, I want to be signed in a specific area only... Help me...

This my code

Main.java

```
public class Longvan extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener {
  ImageView choosenImageView;
  Button choosePicture;
  Button savePicture;
  Bitmap bmp;
  Bitmap alteredBitmap;
  Canvas canvas;
  Paint paint;
  Matrix matrix;
  float downx = 0;
  float downy = 0;
  float upx = 0;
  float upy = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_longvan);
    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }
    else {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }

    choosenImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosenImageView);
    choosePicture = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosePictureButton);
    savePicture = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.SavePictureButton);
    savePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
    choosePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
    choosenImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_longvan, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          downx = event.getX();
          downy = event.getY();
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          upx = event.getX();
          upy = event.getY();
          canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
          choosenImageView.invalidate();
          downx = upx;
          downy = upy;
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          upx = event.getX();
          upy = event.getY();
          canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
          choosenImageView.invalidate();
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
        return true;      
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == choosePicture) {
          Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(
              Intent.ACTION_PICK,
              android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
          startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 0);
        } else if (v == savePicture) {
          if (alteredBitmap != null) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(3);
            contentValues.put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "Draw On Me");
            Uri imageFileUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            try {
              OutputStream imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageFileUri);
              alteredBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, imageFileOS);
              Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Thank you! Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              t.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.v("EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
            }
          }
        }
}

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
          Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          Uri imageFileUri = intent.getData();
          try {
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
            alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getConfig());
            canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            matrix = new Matrix();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
            choosenImageView.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
            choosenImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
          }
        }
      }
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a specific View for inputting Signatures? Something like this: https://github.com/CoatedMoose/CustomViews/tree/master/library/src/com/coatedmoose/customviews

Then, add this setter for the Bitmap:

```
public void setImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.mBitmap = bitmap;
    this.invalidate();
}
```

Or, if you dont want the applied bitmap as part of your signatureview (use it as background, and not as canvas), replace the onDraw method with this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

and then just use `mSignatureView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);`

Edit:

Just create a Class with the code from coatedMoose, and use it in your layout XML:

```
<com.example.myapp.gui.views.SignatureView
  android:id="@+id/signature"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="80dp"/>
```

Somewhere in your code, or even as an XML attribute, you can set the background.

Edit: signatureView class:

```
    package me.other;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * A simple view to capture a path traced onto the screen. Initially intended to be used to captures signatures.
 * 
 * @author Andrew Crichton
 * @version 0.1
 */
public class SignatureView extends View {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint; 
    private Paint bgPaint = new Paint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    private float curX, curY;

    private static final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 4;

    public SignatureView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        setFocusable(true);
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }
    public void setSigColor(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }
    public void setSigColor(int a, int red, int green, int blue) {
        mPaint.setARGB(a, red, green, blue);
    }
    public boolean clearSignature() {
        if (mBitmap != null)
            createFakeMotionEvents();
        if (mCanvas != null) {
            mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mCanvas.drawPaint(bgPaint);
            mPath.reset();
            invalidate();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return this.mBitmap;
    }
    public void setImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        this.invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
        int bitmapWidth = mBitmap != null ? mBitmap.getWidth() : 0;
        int bitmapHeight = mBitmap != null ? mBitmap.getWidth() : 0;
        if (bitmapWidth >= width && bitmapHeight >= height) 
            return;
        if (bitmapWidth < width) 
            bitmapWidth = width;
        if (bitmapHeight < height) 
            bitmapHeight = height;
        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas();
        newCanvas.setBitmap(newBitmap);
        if (mBitmap != null) 
            newCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        mBitmap = newBitmap;
        mCanvas = newCanvas;
    }
    private void createFakeMotionEvents() {
        MotionEvent downEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis()+100, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 1f, 1f ,0);
        MotionEvent upEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis()+100, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 1f, 1f ,0);
        onTouchEvent(downEvent);
        onTouchEvent(upEvent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchDown(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchMove(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchUp();
            break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    /**----------------------------------------------------------
     * Private methods
     **---------------------------------------------------------*/

    private void touchDown(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        curX = x;
        curY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - curX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - curY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(curX, curY, (x + curX)/2, (y + curY)/2);
            curX = x;
            curY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(curX, curY);
        if (mCanvas == null) {
            mCanvas = new Canvas();
            mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
    }
}
```

Some random layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.example.mysignatureviewapp.views.SignatureView 
        android:id="@+id/sign"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="204dp">
    </com.example.mysignatureviewapp.views.SignatureView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the `onCreate()` method:

```
private SignatureView sign;
//
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mysignatureviewlayout);
    sign = (SignatureView) findViewById(R.id.sign);
    sign.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybackgrounddrawable);
}

//get your signature when you press, say, the back button
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Bitmap mySignature = sign.getImage();
    //do something with bitmap
}
```

Getting both the background and the signature:

```
BitmapDrawable mySignature = new BitmapDrawable(sign.getImage());
Drawable background = sign.getBackground();
LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { mySignature, background});
```

Comment: Can you guide more detail? I'm new member of android, so, i feel it difficult?thank you!!!!

Comment: @user1817079 See addition. Just copy/paste the code from github into a new Class, and use it. PS: do you want the applied image as background or as part of the signature (so when you save the signature, should the background be part of that, or is it just decoration and do you just want the signature?)

Comment: i want signature and background as i sign on invoice and save it to sd card.i only want customer sign at specific location on invoice..

Comment: i was code as you guide but my background not show. only show screen white.

Comment: second, if doing so, when i want save both invoice background and signature to file image. I'm what to do?

Comment: @user1817079 I ran my code myself and it work perfectly, so either your drawable is a transparent or white image, or you dont set the contentview with setContentView(R.layout.mylayout). For your second question, see addition

Comment: i think you misunderstood my mind. i want sign as this image:http://www.imagetoo.com/images/signcrc.jpg . Don't want sign as http://www.imagetoo.com/images/nosign.jpg .Can you help me?

Comment: @user1817079 I have neither, but I do have Gmail. Just create an account, and post address.

Comment: Now, I do not know how to do. Can you guide for me?

Comment: Wow, this question has existed since 2012, and I just see it now. Perhaps I should work on getting it hosted in a maven repo at some point.